# A time, times and half a time

Tags: prophecy, revelation

This period of time is mentioned in Daniel and in Revelation, do they refer to the same period in history or are there dissonant interpretations? Further, is John explicitly referring to Daniel or he gets his own inspiration?

Edit:

> 'Time, times and half a time' equates to 'three and a half days/years' and to '1,260 days' and 'forty two months'. It is a common theme in scripture and clearly represents the Church Age (ascension to return of the Son of man) as many commentators affirm

Nigel says this is the usual interpretation, then I am aware also of the interpretation by Newton, who considered (quite arbitrarily) 1260 years starting from 800 a.C.

But both these interpretations, in my view, are wrong since the period on the carpet is the the time when the devil is loose

Comment: Could you add the bible quotes to this question?  I think I'd like to migrate it to Biblical Hermeneutics site - it doesn't really belong on this site unless you can wrap it around a particular denomination's interpretation of the Bible.

Comment: 'Time, times and half a time' equates to 'three and a half days/years' and to '1,260 days' and 'forty two months'. It is a common theme in scripture and clearly represents the Church Age (ascension to return of the Son of man) as many commentators affirm.

Comment: @PeterTurner I agree with the migrate if no denominational view is requested.